# Does ACH+NJA$(\mathbb{R})$ decide the Suslin problem?

Tags: set-theory

Lets start with a couple of axioms in the language of ZFC.

> **ACH.** *Anticontinuum Hypothesis.*
>
> The cardinal $|\mathbb{R}|$ is an aleph fixed points: that is,
>
> $$|\mathbb{R}| = \aleph_{|\mathbb{R}|}$$
>
> (Compare with CH, which says $|\mathbb{R}| = \aleph_1$.)
>
> **NJA$(\mathbb{R})$.** *No jumping axiom for the real line.*
>
> For all cardinals $\kappa,$ we have:
>
> $$\kappa < |\mathbb{R}| \rightarrow 2^\kappa \leq |\mathbb{R}|$$

Taken together, these axioms give us a huge wilderness of cardinals $\kappa$ such that $2^\kappa = |\mathbb{R}|$. Here's a tiny initial portion of them:

$$\aleph_0, \aleph_1,\aleph_2, \ldots \aleph_{\omega},\aleph_{\omega+1},\ldots, \aleph_{\aleph_1}, \ldots\aleph_{\aleph_\omega},\ldots$$

Okay. It is known that the Suslin problem is independent of both CH and $\neg$CH. I'm hoping that the combination of ACH (which is significantly stronger than $\neg$CH) and the assumption that a crapload of cardinals now satisfy $2^\kappa = |\mathbb{R}|$ will be a little more opinionated on this issue.

> **Question.** Can we somehow use these cardinals to either construct a [Suslin line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suslin%27s_problem), or else prove that no Suslin line exists?
>
> In other words, does ACH+NJA$(\mathbb{R})$ decide the Suslin problem?

Comment: What about the ACHE axiom stating an anticontinuum hypothesis everywhere, and its various extensions like STOMACHACHE, HEADACHE, and HEARTACHE?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, nice. I'd add the BUTTACHE axiom, except that it's a real pain in the arse ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, these axioms do not suffice: They are consistent with $\mathsf{MA} $ (in the presence of inaccessibles, say), which implies that there are no Suslin lines. But adding a Cohen real adds Suslin lines (this is a result of Shelah) and does not affect cardinal arithmetic.

Comment: Let me check if I got this right: Your forcing is just the usual finite product forcing to make $\operatorname{MA}$ true and $2^{\aleph_0} = \kappa$, where $\kappa$ is the inaccessible in your ground model?

Comment: Yes, that gives us the first part. For the second, just add one Cohen real to this model of $\mathsf {MA} $.

Comment: That's what I figured. Thank you!

Comment: Can we obtain consistency of the lack of  a Suslin line  plus ACH plus NJA(R) without requiring an inaccessible cardinal?

Comment: @user254665 Yes, we can. Start in a model with MA and let $\kappa$ be a $\beth$-fixed point of uncountable cofinality. If you now add $\kappa$ many random reals, the resulting model satisfies ACH and NJA(R) and also has no Suslin trees by a result of Laver (R. Laver, Random reals and Souslin trees. Proc. Am. Math. Soc 100, no. 3 (1987)).

Comment: @MihaHabič. Thank you. I believe that in conjunction with the second part of the A by Andres Caicedo, this completely answers the original Q.